# What is wrong with this npm semver?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg, semantic-versioning

I want do add following dependency to package.json of my npm package:

```
"redux-saga": "^1.0.0-beta.0 || ^0.16.0"`.
```

So when I install this package of mine inside different project that already has

```
"redux-saga": "^1.0.0-beta.1
```

I expect npm/yarn to install only `1.0.0-beta.1` inside project's `node_modules`. However, it installs `0.16.0` transitively inside my package.

So I checked with [semver calculator](https://semver.npmjs.com/) and got weird results for `redux-saga` package:

- `^1.0.0-beta.0 || ^0.16.0` only allows `0.16.0` - this is unexpected
- `^1.0.0-beta.0 || ^0.15.0` allows expected

  ```
  0.15.0 0.15.1 0.15.2
  0.15.3 0.15.4 0.15.5
  0.15.6 1.0.0-beta.0 1.0.0-beta.1
  ```

I could not find any explanation in docs. My question is - if it's not a bug, then why  `^1.0.0-beta.0 || ^0.16.0` does not allow `1.0.0-beta.1`?

Comment: That definitely seems wrong to me.

Comment: weird, looks like inclusive comparison is somehow broken? `<=1.0.0-beta.0` does not include beta.0 either

Answer (score 1):

My question has been answered on npm community [forums](https://npm.community/t/wrong-version-is-installed-when-dependency-is-specified-as-union-range/1529).

`0.16.0` gets installed because it is tagged `latest`, and npm prioritizes `latest` tag. The algorithm can be found in [npm-pick-manifest](https://github.com/zkat/npm-pick-manifest) package.

I ended up using [yarn resolutions](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) to solve versions conflict

Comment: Thank you for following up on this. Is there a way to negate the `latest` tag in your query?

Comment: Ended up using `yarn resolutions` in a project that consumes the library

Comment: A link to `yarn resolutions` in your answer would probably be useful to somebody who stumbles into the same problem.